# Tracking features in consecutive frames

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

How will one implement tracking features in 2 consecutive frames? The idea is to use a grid of points for the first frame and the LK algorithm for the second frame and match features in both those frames indefinitely for a video stream but I'm unsure how to implement this in opencv. I'm using opencv 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an interesting tutorial in [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html). It uses the Python API but you can easily translate it in C++.

You can also find a pure C++ example in OpenCV's Github repo: [lkdemo.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/lkdemo.cpp)

Comment: How will you be able to use the RANSAC algorithm on the code provided? Basically remove outliers to that we can detect objects?

Comment: I am not aware of a RANSAC implementation (in OpenCV) for addressing this particular issue.